# Pysmell install error with Textmate?

Tags: python, textmate

I'm trying to install PySmell with Textmate -

I'm using TextMate on Mac OS, and to complicate things a bit, I'm using Brew and several virtual environments.  In my case, I'm just trying to install Pysmell in my default version of Python.

I've followed the instructions for the install - and can import pysmell through a python shell - so that looks like it works.  I've also generated a tags file for my project

However, If I try to invoke alt/escape within TextMate, I get this text generated right after my cursor point:

```
usage: pysmell [-h] [-v] [-x [package [package ...]]] [-o OUTPUT] [-i INPUT]
               [-t] [-d]
               package [package ...]
pysmell: error: no such option: -c
```

I'm thinking I have something setup wrong - anyone have any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doh!

I accidentally created my TM_PYTHON link to pysmell and not python.  Working fine now...